# Cómo puedo hacer para que esta macro no inserte filas vacías en otra hoja del libro?

Tags: vba

La macro tiene este problema:

- Si Mónica compra solo flores (ver imagen 1), entonces en Hoja 2 inserta 4 filas vacías.
- Si Mónica compra solo flores y papel regalo, entonces en  Hoja 2 inserta 3 filas vacías.
- Si Mónica compra solo flores, papel regalo y tarjeta, entonces en Hoja 2 inserta 2 filas (ver imagen 2).

Cómo puedo hacer para que la macro no haga eso de insertar filas vacías en la Hoja 2?

[image: Tabla "Compras del Cliente"]

[image: Tabla "Lista de Ventas"]

```
Sub Compras_del_Cliente()

    'Compras del cliente Macro
    Sheets("Hoja2").Select
    Range("A9:A13").EntireRow.Insert

    'Nombre / Empresa
    Sheets("Hoja1").Select
    Range("C9").Copy      
    Sheets("Hoja2").Select
    Range("A9").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    'Código
    Sheets("Hoja1").Select
    If Range("B12:B16").Select <> Empty Then
        Range("B12:B16").Copy 
    End If
    Sheets("Hoja2").Select
    Range("C9").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    'Descripción del Producto
    Sheets("Hoja1").Select
    If Range("C12:C16").Select <> Empty Then
        Range("C12:C16").Copy    
    End If
    Sheets("Hoja2").Select
    Range("B9").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    'Cantidad
    Sheets("Hoja1").Select
    If Range("D12:D16").Select <> Empty Then
        Range("D12:D16").Copy    
    End If
    Sheets("Hoja2").Select
    Range("D9").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    'Precio
    Sheets("Hoja1").Select
    If Range("E12:E16").Select <> Empty Then
        Range("E12:E16").Copy    
    End If
    Sheets("Hoja2").Select
    Range("E9").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub

Sub Borrar()
    'Botón para borrar valores en la tabla "Compras del CLIENTE" en Hoja 1
    Range("C9").Value = Empty
    Range("B12:B16").Value = Empty
    Range("C12:C16").Value = Empty
    Range("D12:D16").Value = Empty
    Range("E12:E16").Value = Empty
End Sub

Sub Eliminar_venta()
    'Botón para eliminar venta en la tabla "Lista de VENTAS" en la Hoja 2
    Sheets("Hoja2").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    'Código
    Sheets("Hoja1").Select
    If Range("B12:B16").Select <> Empty Then
        Range("B12:B16").Copy 
    End If
    Sheets("Hoja2").Select
    Range("C9").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

En ésta parte del código, estás diciendo, que si en el rango de celdas que va, desde B12 a B16, hay algún dato, o sea, es distinto a Empty, copie el rango completo y lo pegue en la hoja 2 a partir de la celda C9

No estás diciendo que copie las celdas con datos, estás diciendo que si en alguna celda hay datos, las copie todas.

Estas copiando 5 filas independientemente de que haya datos en una (flores), en dos (flores y papel) o en tres (flores, papel y tarjetas). Como copias las cinco filas, te pegará las filas con datos y las filas vacías, de ahí que te pegue esas líneas en blanco que dices.

La forma de evitarlo, sería evaluar fila a fila, si hay datos que te copie la celda con datos.

```
    'Código
    Sheets("Hoja1").Select
    If Range("B12").Select <> Empty Then
        Range("B12").Copy 
    End If
    Sheets("Hoja2").Select
    Range("C9").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Podrías crear un bucle que valide que en el rango de filas vaya encontrando datos, si los encuentra, lo copie y lo vaya pegando en la hoja 2

```
'seleccionamos la hoja donde se copiarán los datos
Sheets("Hoja1").Select
'declaramos variables de rango y celdas en el rango
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
'metemos el rango B12:B16 en la variable de rango rng
Set rng = Range("B12:B16")
'hacemos un bucle del rango
For Each cell In rng
    'volvemos a selecionar la hoja a copiar para las iteraciones del bucle
    Sheets("Hoja1").Select
    'si la celda seleccionada que corresponde con el bucle no está vacía
    If cell.Select <> Empty Then
        'la copiamos
        cell.Copy
    End If
    'seleccionamos la hoja 2
    Sheets("Hoja2").Select
    'si la celda 9 de la fila 3 (C9) está vacía
    If IsEmpty(Cells(9, 3)) Then
        'pegamos lo que se había copiado
        Cells(9, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        'si la anterio no está vacía pero si lo está la siguiente
        ElseIf IsEmpty(Cells(10, 3)) Then
            Cells(10, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            ElseIf IsEmpty(Cells(11, 3)) Then
                Cells(11, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                ElseIf IsEmpty(Cells(12, 3)) Then
                    Cells(12, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    ElseIf IsEmpty(Cells(13, 3)) Then
                        Cells(13, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                        ElseIf IsEmpty(Cells(14, 3)) Then
                            Cells(14, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                        End If
Next cell
```

Comment: Soy @victorvelasquez. Gracias por tu tiempo, amigo! Te cuento que sustituí las funciones que ya tenia en la macro para el asunto CODIGO, por la que me sugeriste para crear bucle; pero la bendita macro quedó haciendo lo mismo que ya había planteado antes como mi problema. No sé si insista mas con eso; pues ya tengo bastante tiempo tratando de resolver eso, sin resultado alguno. Por ello es que me decidí a buscar ayuda en la red. Agradezco pues la atención dispensada, por algunos de los que aquí se ocuparon en mi enredo informático! Saludos!

Comment: Pues la respuesta que te puse, está probada y funciona como pides, por lo que creo que estás añadiendo algo a mi código que no deberías de agregar y hace que te añada filas en blanco.

Comment: Voy a revisar, my brother! No sabes las ganas que tengo de ver que la vaina funcione, y escribir aquí para ti un grandioso agradecimiento en letras mayusculas, chamo!!!

Comment: Amigo el.Trasgu, tu respuesta a mi primer proyecto ha sido maravillosa. TE FELICITO MUY SINCERAMENTE Y AGRADEZCO TU APORTE! Es un placer contar contigo! Mi saludo para ti!!!